# How have dairy farms been repurposed?

Tags: commercial-farming, agriculture

I'm looking for instances, ideally small family farms exhibited in news articles, for converting their farm into an industry not centered around animals.

It would be great if you can include specifics such as if they changed the types of crops rotated or creative methods their farm was changed.

I found some articles about Hälsa, but it just seems like a product marketing scheme. The same with Miyoko's Creamery. I do not want more articles about plant-based companies supposedly working on converting dairy farms to whatever plant product they sell.

Comment: A farm without cows is just land, right? Land can be used for anything. And if we're not considering slaughtering the surplus cows, a cow on a farm that will never be milked or slaughtered is an animal sanctuary (supported by charity) or a zoo.

Comment: @MatthewMartin My inquiry is about the conversion of dairy land. I don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: What is special about dairyland? Where I live, in Washington, DC, all the dairy farms were literally converted to residential housing.  I'm not sure where this question is going-- is it about no-kill farming? Veganic farming is a thing.

Comment: I live in Wisconsin: 1.3M cows spread across nearly 8k dairy farms, more than any other state. Here, hundreds of dairy farms are lost every year. Here and nationally, intensive dairy farming operations are increasing. The most common rejection of veganism is because Wisconsinites want to support farmers (i.e., the WI economy). Besides the actual practices done in farms (insemination, cow-calf separation, slaughter age, living conditions), it would be better to follow up with practical real world examples of dairy farms being converted. People wonder, "Well, what are WI farmers supposed to do?"

Comment: Also, it's a valid question. It shouldn't need justification.

Comment: I don't know about dairy, but I do know that chicken farms (that were storing chickens indoors in long, enclosed sheds and whoose ground is covered in in rich chicken poop) have trivially been converteed to mushroom farms, since all of the infrastructure and inputs are already in-place. And mushrooms are a high-value crop.